# How to solve $x-\sin x = \dfrac {\pi}{10}$?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

Solve $x-\sin x = \dfrac {\pi}{10}$.

I got $1.26$ using Newton Raphson method but Is there any other alternative method?

Comment: Since $|1.26 - \sin(1.26) - \pi/10| \ge .006$, it follows $1.26$ is not a solution of the equation. So your question is unclear.

Comment: @LeeMosher, how does that make the question unclear?  The error is probably due to OP rounding too much and/or too soon.

Comment: @LeeMosher, What's unclear in the question? My answer might be mistake.

Comment: It makes the question unclear because the premise is wrong. Is the OP asking how to get lower errors? The answer would be: use the same method and iterate longer. Is the OP asking for different methods of finding approximate solutions? The answer would be yes, there are different methods, but that is a broad question. Is the OP asking how to find the closest answer to the hundredths digit? And so on...

Comment: @LeeMosher, I am looking for different method of solution.

Comment: Please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm for alternative methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with fixed point iteration, where you have two curves $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\sin{x}+\frac{\pi}{10}$ and you compute the intersection of both with a guessed $x$ value, being the seed $x^0$ .

This scheme is presented as follows:
$$x^{n+1}=g(x^{n})=\sin{x^n}+\frac{\pi}{10} \tag{1}$$

This scheme converges to the root $x^*$  within an interval in which the derivative of $g(x)$ is less that unity, $i.e$ $x^0\in(-\pi,\pi)$.
This can be proved computing the error:
$$|x^{n+1}-x^*|=|g(x^n)-g(x^*)|\leq L|x^n-x^*|$$
The bounding constant $L$ must be less that unity for $(1)$ to converge. This $L$ coincides with:
$$L=\max{|g'(x)|}$$

Since $g'(x) = \cos{x}$ and its maximum value is 1 in $x=\pm \pi$, equation $(1)$ will always converge to $x^*$ if the seed is chosen within $x^0\in(-\pi,\pi)$

Comment: Sorry, didn't intend to copy your answer. But fixed point iteration always pops into my head when I see equations similar to this :).

Comment: @MrYouMath don't worry about that. You're right, $x=f(x)$ is almost always suitable for fixed point method except when $L>1$. :)

Answer (score 0):

One other method is to use fixed point iteration. Rewrite: $x = \phi(x)=\sin(x)+\pi/10$. The iteration is

$x_{k+1}=\phi(x_{k})=\sin(x_k)+\pi/10$.

Start with $x = 0$ and iterate 8-9 steps and you will get a pretty good numerical solution.

Answer (score 0):

defining $$f(x)=x-\sin(x)-\frac{\pi}{10}$$ and $$f'(x)=1-\cos(x)\geq 0$$ and $$f(0)<0$$ and $$f(2\pi)>0$$ ntherefore we get only one solution $$x\approx 1.26894786483261674188$$